# Translating SAS code for a GLMM with a spatial-autocorrelation covariance structure to R

Tags: r, sas

I have some SAS code running three different GLMMs, and I need to run the same in R. Can anyone help me translate? I never worked with SAS before. I've been using 'glmer.nb' from lme4 for this, but am willing to change if necessary. The SAS code is below.

```
libname dataset 'H:\ReefSAS';

PROC IMPORT DATAFILE = "H:\ReefSAS\reefdatasas.xls"
OUT = reefdata DBMS = xls REPLACE;
GETNAMES = yes;
RUN;

/*] "date"  "reefID"  "station"  "densClass" 
"easting"  "northing"  "altitude"  "density"  */

/* three different spatial structures  */

proc mixed data=reefdata;
  class date station densClass;
  model density =station densClass;
  Random reefID;
  repeated date/ TYPE=SP(EXPGA)(easting northing) subject=reefID; 
run;

proc mixed data=reefdata;
  class date station densClass;
  model density =station densClass;
  Random reefID;
  repeated date/ TYPE=SP(GAUGA)(easting northing) subject=reefID; 
run;

proc mixed data=reefdata;
  class date station densClass;
  model density =station densClass;
  Random reefID;
  repeated date/ TYPE=SP(SPHGA)(easting northing) subject=reefID; 
run;​
```

Edit: My current code has three options, one working (lme::nlme) and two not working (glmer.nb::lme4 and nlme::nlme). To be honest I'm not sure I have translated the statements from SAS correctly. I would also like to point out that the formulations are linear at this moment, but the idea is to build up the fixed effects with combinations of other variables in a nonlinear fashion once I get this running. The code I have so far:

```
library(lme4) # works, but it does not account for spatial auto-correlation
glmer.nb(density~date+densClass+1|reefID, data=reefdata)

library(nlme) # does not run, error below
nlme(model=density~alpha*date + beta*densClass, data=reefdata,
         fixed=alpha+beta~date*densClass,
         random=density~1|reefID,
         start=list(fixed=0.05, alpha=0.05, beta=0.05),
         correlation=corExp(form=~easting+northing |reefID))
# Error in nlme.formula(model = densAVG ~ alpha * dateLvls + beta * densClass, : starting values for the 'fixed' component are not the correct length

library(nlme) # works but does not incorporate spatial auto-correlation
lme(density~date+densClass, random=~1|reefID, data=reefdata)
```

Comment: Well, basically I've been reading a lot since yesterday, I added reefID as a random effect, but I'm not sure what and how I should formulate the line that says 'repeated'. So far, [this comment][1] sums up pretty well what I got on the subject. The formulation I got so far is below, but it doesn't work. The error says 'failed to reduce deviance in  pwrssUpdate'.

    glmer.nb(density~date+(easting+northing|reefID), data=reefdata)

[1]: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/5350/94166

Comment: `glmer.nb` is a GLMM implementation for the negative binomial distribution. Is this what you want? I have never used or seen syntax like in your `repeated` statement. Perhaps this code should at least get you going: `glmer(formula = density ~ station + densClass + (1|reefID),data = reefdata)`

Comment: This is good material to add to your question and perhaps pull out some of the info in the link.